# Robust Communication Network in Swarm Robotics

Tags: mobile-robot, wireless, swarm, reference-request, networking

I'm looking into best practices to build robust wireless communication networks for a swarm of ground based mobile robots. In particular the mobile robots have cellular connectivity, but some areas may have better signal, so a smart navigation strategy is needed to coordinate the swarm to send some robots to the area of greater coverage and relay the signal wireless to other robots.

What navigation strategies do you suggest? If you can share an open source reference implementation it would be great.